# Boundary of a region and area

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that if $h(z)=1/z+c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2+\ldots $ is analytic and injective for $0<|z|<1$, then $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} n|c_n|^2\leq 1$. 
>   Hint : Calculate the area of the complement of $h(D_{\rho}(0)-\lbrace0 \rbrace)$ and let $\rho \rightarrow 1$.
>   (Complex Analysis, Stein-Shakarchi p.108)

Intuitively the complement of $h(D_{\rho}(0)-\lbrace0 \rbrace )$ is a closed and bounded region of the plane delimited by a Jordan curve : $\theta \rightarrow h(\rho e^{i\theta})$ (since $h$ is injective it is easy to see that this curve is non-self-intersecting).
Let us assume that fact is true. We can use Green's formula in order to compute this area : $$ \begin{aligned}
\mathcal{A}&=\frac{1}{2}\Im (\int _{|z|=\rho}h'(z)\overline{h(z)}dz)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Im (\int _{0}^{2\pi}i\rho e^{it}\lbrace -\rho ^{-2}e^{-2it}+c_1+\sum_{n\geq 1}nc_n\rho^{n-1}e^{i(n-1)t}\rbrace\lbrace \rho ^{-1}e^{it}+\overline{c_0}+\sum _{n\geq 1}\overline{c_n}\rho ^ne^{int}\rbrace dt\\
&=\pi(\frac {-1}{\rho ^2}+\sum _{n\geq 1}n|c_n|^2\rho^{2n}) \text { by using orthogonality of {$e^{int}$}.}
\end{aligned}
$$

Clearly I made a sign mistake but I don't see where. If I had obtained $\pi(\frac {1}{\rho ^2}-\sum _{n\geq 1}n|c_n|^2\rho^{2n}) $ I can conclude by using the fact that an area is always nonnegative and letting tend $\rho$ to $1$.
Moreover I don't see a simple way in order to prove my initial assumption.

Comment: See also [Gronwall's area theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_quarter_theorem#Gronwall.27s_area_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

> Clearly I made a sign mistake but I don't see where.

Right at the beginning. Since $f$ has a pole in $0$, the curve $f(\rho e^{it})$ is traversed in the negative sense, so the area is

$$-\frac{1}{2} \Im \int_{\lvert z\rvert = \rho} h'(z)\overline{h(z)}\,dz.$$